# CRM iFrame associated view record count MS Dynamics

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a `crmForm` with an iFrame that displays an associeted Entity.  I want to validate that the associated view in the `iFrame` has records when the user saves the parent `crmform`.  Using javascript, how can I find the record count of the crmGrid in the `iFrame`.

The closest I come is

```
var frameDoc = document.getElementById('IFrame_contacts').contentWindow.document;
var recordcount = frameDoc.all['crmGrid'].innergrid.Allrecords.lenght;
```

That just gives me an `innergrid` not found error.

Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You want `var recordcount = frameDoc.getElementById("crmGrid").InnerGrid.SelectedRecords.length;`

Comment: Turns out that my iFrame was still loading.  When I added code to  the onstatuschange event I got it to work.  Thanks for your reply

Comment: NOTE: This will not work in CRM 2011 UR12.  InnerGrid was removed (I assume so they could support other browsers).